# Read Permission denied on excel file within web solution

Tags: asp.net, file-permissions

I am having an issue where an excel file within a content folder within my ASP.Net mvc application is giving me an an access denied error. This for some reason is only failing in my dev environment, it works perfectly in my prod environment. The path is stored in a key in my web.config and is

`<add key="ExcelPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\content\template.xlsx"/>`

I have set permissions on the folder to everyone to see if that works but I still get the same error. The aspnet user and network service bothe have full access to the folder so I'm slightly perplexed as to what the issue is as it is working perfectly in another environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to set it your application on

> fulltrust

in your web.config and can you post your web.config ,its probably their where you need to see first.

regards
Alok